# How to design an asynchronous handling of both nanomsg socket and tty or Netlink?

Tags: linux, asynchronous, serial-port, netlink, nanomsg

How can I write a main loop (in C for Linux system) which blocks while waiting for messages from multiple sources such as
**a )** a nanomsg socket and serial port, or
**b )** a nanomsg socket and Netlink socket?

Where to start?

I think I could poll the nanomsg socket, then poll the serial port, then sleep for e.g. 0.1 sec, but this is a pattern I'd like to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If the above posted approach is the way you do not want to take, then one may do this:

1 )
Instantiate a thread with an autonomous **serial port**-scanner, equip this thread with  a **`PAIR/PAIR`** or **`PUSH/PULL`** ( as observed from the port scanner-thread side ) connection with the main, best using a zero or low overhead transport-class ~ `inproc://` or `ipc://` ( `tcp://` transport-class simply spends just too much overheads to deliver inter-thread signalling / messaging ). Make this scanner-thread send whatever you need over this uplink to the main, whenever you feel that appropriate.

2 )
Instantiate a thread with an autonomous **[nanomsg](/questions/tagged/nanomsg)**-scanner, equip this thread with a **`PAIR/PAIR`** or **`PUSH/PULL`** ( as observed from the socket scanner-thread side ) connection with the main, best using a zero or low overhead transport-class ~ `inproc://` or `ipc://`. Make this scanner-thread send whatever you need over this uplink to the main, whenever you feel that appropriate.

3 )
Equip the `main()` with both respective counterparties ( 2x `PAIR`-s or 2x `PULL`-s ), as decided in 1 ) and 2 ), and maintain this inter-thread signalling / messaging plane infrastructure up and running.

4 )
Enjoy the ***"comfort"* of a trivial blocking call to a `.poll()`** in the `main(){...}` ( as you wished above, whereas I professionally advocate for using a non-blocking code, always ... but also recognise, but not respect, your expressed wish above to loose your own code control, during indeterministically long waiting for an unblocking event - if it ever comes )

5 )
Given a `.poll()` has got some message, do a `aRetCODE = nn_recv( aS, &B, aBsz, NN_DONTWAIT );` reading the respective signalled uplink from either of the scanner-threads.

6 )
Loop.